# Which sentences is better?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have a question. Which sentence is better?

1. I have sent electronic copies of all my documents to your
   University.
2. I am sending electronic copies of all my documents to your University.
3. Could you please review my documents and determine whether I qualify to be admitted to postgraduate studies.
4. Would you please review my documents and determine whether these qualify me for admission to postgraduate studies.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first pair, neither one is inherently better - they mean different things.  #1 states that you have *already* sent the documents ([past tense](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarbook/verbs/the-past-simple-tense/)), while #2 states that you're *currently* sending them, perhaps as attachments in the same email ([present progressive tense](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarbook/verbs/the-present-progressive-tense/)).

For the second pair, both are acceptable, but #4 is a more passive phrasing, which is considered more polite.  However, you might want to use `they` instead of `these`, depending on whether you've already sent them (option #1) or you're currently sending them (option #2).

Comment: I would add that option 2 implies that the copies are attached to an email with that statement.